# CMake ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON directory does not exist

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to install OpenCV and in order to do it I'm following this  [tutorial](https://pydeeplearning.com/opencv/install-opencv3-with-anaconda-python3-6-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

But when it comes to building OpenCV, when using the cmake command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D WITH_CUDA=OFF \
-D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/ayush/soft/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON
```

I have the following error:

> CMake Error: The source directory
>   "/mnt/c/Users/celia/OC/Dogs/Dogs/opencv-3.4.1/build/ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON"
>   does not exist.

I have no idea how to fix this..

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running CMake from the command line, you need to specify the path to your *source directory* (containing the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file), or the path to an existing build directory. See the documentation [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#generate-a-project-buildsystem). Because you did not provide a path, CMake interpreted the last argument (`ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON`) as the path, which is probably not what you intended.

Seeing that you are running from your `build` directory, the path to your source should be the parent directory (`..`). Try this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D WITH_CUDA=OFF \
-D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/ayush/soft/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON ..
```